# Coprime Integers Proof Check

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

$\gcd(a,b)=1$ if and only if there is no prime $p$ such that $p|a$ and $p|b$

Prove it.

So I went about doing it through contradiction: 
If $p|a$ and $p|b$ then $p|(x_{1})(x_{2})(x_{3})...$ where $(x_{1})(x_{2})(x_{3})... = a$ and $x$ are all prime and $p|(y_{1})(y_{2})(y_{3})...$ where $(y_{1})(y_{2})(y_{3})... = b$ and $y$ are all prime. Essentially applying the Fundamental theorem of Arithmetic

Which means that there is some $x$ and $y$ that $p$ can divide which means that $a$ and $b$ are not coprime therefore proving the statement true.

I did not want to prove it through contradiction (and I'm not even sure if I did it correctly) so could I get some help with this? Thanks.

Comment: I think proving by contradiction is a lot simpler if you use the fact that $\gcd(a,b)=1$ if and only if there exists $x$ and $y$ integers such that $ax+by=1$.

Answer (score 4):

The statement has two parts, being if and only if.

1. If there is such a naughty $p$, then $\gcd(a,b)\neq 1$.
2. If there is no such  $p$, then $\gcd(a,b)=1$.

Your attempt was to prove 1; you were moderately successful.  Simpler is to point out that $p$ must divide the gcd, hence the gcd$\ge p>1$.

The trickier part is part 2.  There are many proofs, depending on what tools you've been given.

Comment: +1, I was going to answer the same thing, but you beat me to it.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** $ $ Contrapositively: the greatest common divisor is $> 1\!\iff\!$ there is a common divisor $> 1$ $\iff $ there is a common prime divisor.